# How to get the value of a cloned option select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone, html-select

I have a very large dropdown menue in html with "select option". Because I want to use this menu multiple times, I want duplicate the dropdown menu by using jQuery "clone and appendTo".

But how do I get the value of the cloned dropdown menu? Here is what I tried. It gives me back "undefined" for selectedValueCar2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



  <p>first box here:</p>
  <select id="list1" onchange="fn1();">
    <option value ="car1000">Audi A2 (2001)</option>
    <option value ="car1010">Audi A3 (2004)</option>
    <option value ="car1020">Audi A5 (2009)</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id="list2"><p>second box here:</p></div>
  <script>
    $( "#list1" ).clone().appendTo( "#list2");
  </script>

<script>
  function fn1(){
selectedValueCar = document.getElementById("list1").value;
        console.log(selectedValueCar);
selectedValueCar2 = document.getElementById("list2").value;
        console.log(selectedValueCar2);
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to "clone" html element, you must get it's Html. Then load it into a variable, so that you could use it as html somewhere else. Take a look at my example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open the page in broswer and inspect it, you will see what the problem is.

It is cloning the whole `<select id="list1">...</select>` into `<select id="list2">` and not just the `<option>` tags. So `document.getElementById("list2").value` has no value (`<option value="xxx">`) and so you see "undefined"

[HTML view after clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqS95.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks at all. My solution is now, that I change the ID-Attribute, when cloning.

```
  <div id="list2"><p>second box here:</p></div>
  <script>
    $("#list1").clone().attr("id","list5").appendTo("#list2");
  </script>
```